# How do I turn off calendar notifications in ubuntu touch?

Tags: sound, ubuntu-touch, notification, calendar

I'm using ubuntu touch on MX4. 15.04 r2. I use the calendar app, this one is up to date. I can't seem to turn off calendar notifications for events on my calendar. I've looked in system settings and in app settings, but can't find any related settings. Each event has reminder settings, these are turned off. Still I get reminders (So at full volume, also in the middle of the night). Since reminders don't linger in the notification area, I can't even see which events they are for, and I haven't figured out how long in advance they notify. I can't set volume for this notification or ringtone. Am I missing a setting in an obvious location? Something seems to be broken...
I found: 
 - System settings - Notifications (calendar is not listed. Gmail is, but calendar isn't)
 - System settings - Sound - Message received (this does not govern the calendar related notification sound)
 - System settings - sound - Ringtone (also not the right one)

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me troubleshoot this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is already known. In oder to bring about a speedy fix, I recommend heading over to Launchpad and mark the bug as affecting you too and also subscribe to it. This will increase the 'heat' for this issue and hopefully we can have it fixed soon.

As a (unsatisfactory) work around I resolved to not use notifications in my calendar events for the time being. :(

[[calendar] Reminder notifications are not integrated into system notifications](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-calendar-app/+bug/1440111)

Comment: Thanks! sidenote: The workaround doesn't really apply for me, the alarm also rings for events without reminders/notifications. In effect (because it wakes me up at night) I can't have a synced calendar on my phone.

Comment: Come on guys and gals... Lets get the heat up on this bug. Poor Maarten needs this fixed or he will never have a full night of sleep again. ;-)

Comment: Haha I'm really losing sleep over this issue... ;) Thanks anyway, we'll see when it gets resolved